# Rails 4 - i18n country_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to implement [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem into my app so that a user could select a country during the registration process(devise).

I want list of countries to be translated based on user's locale. It's actually translated in few [languages](https://www.github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#iso-3166-1-alpha-2-codes)

There is this gem [i18n-country-translations](https://www.github.com/onomojo/i18n-country-translations), which contains list of countries on many different languages. How do I implement those translations when I try to select countries?

I've also found another gem from the same author [i18n_country_select](https://www.github.com/onomojo/i18n_country_select). But, when I  try to use it like this:

```
<%= f.country_code_select(:user, :country) %>
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `to_country_code_select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Select:0x007f182d81abe0>
```

Comment: did you try without the f. ?

Comment: yes, the error appears in that case as well

Comment: umm, according to https://github.com/onomojo/i18n_country_select/blob/master/lib/i18n_country_select/form_helpers.rb#L3 the first parameter is object_name , so (I am guessing) you have @user in your view available?

Comment: yes, for edit_user where the country selection is happening. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I generally use carmen for country selection, but I don't understand how to and tag is getting appended.

Comment: Can you post the full form code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
    f.country_select (:user, :country_code)
```